# JS/JQuery library that allow to show dynamic table information

Tags: jquery

There are at least 2 ways to show and reload information in table:
-to rebuild table each time when new data arrives;
-to update table's cells if they changes, adding or deleting rows one by one if needed.
I've used the first approach, but now I want to add some JQuery UI effects, but I don't think that adding a "slider" or "selectable" every 3 seconds to 100 rows is a good idea. Is there any libraries for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

the only animation that would work for me in this kind situation is a custom jQuery animation which would change the backgroundcolor, fading it to its 'to be' color. this way the attention gets drawn, but not too much to make people sick.

Edit: Since you cant `.animate()` the background color you need to use this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Comment: what animation are you talking about? I need to show data that changes over time. animation is not an issue here.

Comment: my suggestion is you just use a table with some color-effect for the newly added data...

Comment: no. I need to make a data loading without rerendering a table.